# How do I add two column values in a table with CQL?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am needing to add two values together to create a third value with CQL. Is there any way to do this? My table has the columns `number_of_x` and `number_of_y` and I am trying to create `total`. I did an update on the table with a set command as follows:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET total = number_of_x + number_of_y ;
```

When I run that I get the message back saying:

```
no viable alternative at input ';'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/update_r.html). assignment is one of:

```
column_name = value
set_or_list_item = set_or_list_item ( + | - ) ...
map_name = map_name ( + | - ) ...
map_name = map_name ( + | - ) { map_key : map_value, ... } 
column_name [ term ] = value
counter_column_name = counter_column_name ( + | - ) integer
```

And you cannot mix counter and non counter columns in the same table so what you are describing is impossible in a single statement. But you can do a read before write:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table ( total int, x int, y int, key text PRIMARY KEY )
INSERT INTO my_table (key, x, y) VALUES ('CUST_1', 1, 1);
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE key = 'CUST_1';

 key    | total | x | y
--------+-------+---+---
 CUST_1 |  null | 1 | 1

UPDATE my_table SET total = 2 WHERE key = 'CUST_1' IF x = 1 AND y = 1;

 [applied]
-----------
      True

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE key = 'CUST_1';

 key    | total | x | y
--------+-------+---+---
 CUST_1 |     2 | 1 | 1
```

The `IF` clause will handle concurrency issues if x or y was updated since the `SELECT`. You can than retry again if `applied` is `False`.

My recommendation however in this scenario is for your application to just read both `x` and `y`, then do addition locally as it will perform MUCH better.

If you really want C* to do the addition for you, there is a [sum aggregate function](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryStdAggregate.html) in 2.2+ but it will require updating your schema a little:

```
CREATE TABLE table_for_aggregate (key text, type text, value int, PRIMARY KEY (key, type));

INSERT INTO table_for_aggregate (key, type, value) VALUES ('CUST_1', 'X', 1);
INSERT INTO table_for_aggregate (key, type, value) VALUES ('CUST_1', 'Y', 1);

SELECT sum(value) from table_for_aggregate WHERE key = 'CUST_1';

 system.sum(value)
-------------------
                 2
```